# How do I search for a versioned rpm capability?

Tags: rpm, dependencies

I would like to search the rpm database on the "CAPABILITY" of rpms but this seems to be poorly defined. See example below.

on Red Hat, the glibc rpm provides the following capability:

```
rpm -q --provides glibc
...
glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7
```

I want to find out which rpms depend specifically on *this* version of glibc. For instance, nscd does:

```
rpm -q --requires nscd
...
glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7
...
```

But I can't find a way of querying the rpm database. I feel I should be able to:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires "glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7"
no package requires glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7
```

Is there a convenient way of finding this information? CAPABILITY is not well defined in the man pages.